# You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module plugin, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, cucumber, cypress

When I try to run the testcases in cypress that time I am getting the error regarding the babel.

```
Error: [BABEL]: You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module plugin, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously. (While processing: C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-class-properties\lib\index.js) while parsing file: C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\cypress\support\e2e.js
    at loadCodeDefault (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\module-types.js:63:9)
    at loadCodeDefault.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at requireModule (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:193:46)
    at requireModule.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at loadPlugin (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:48:24)
    at loadPlugin.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at createDescriptor (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:139:16)
    at createDescriptor.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at evaluateSync (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\gensync\index.js:251:28)
    at C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\gensync\index.js:31:34
    at Array.map (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at Function.sync (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\gensync\index.js:31:22)
    at Function.all (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\gensync\index.js:210:24)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at createDescriptors (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:41)
    at createDescriptors.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at createPluginDescriptors (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:98:17)
    at createPluginDescriptors.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:64:32
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:21:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at evaluateSync (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\gensync\index.js:251:28)
    at Function.sync (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\gensync\index.js:89:14)
    at sync (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:62:25)
    at sync (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\gensync\index.js:182:19)
    at onFirstPause (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\gensync\index.js:210:24)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at cachedFunction (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:52:46)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at mergeChainOpts (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:347:34)
    at mergeChainOpts.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at chainWalker (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:314:14)
    at chainWalker.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at buildRootChain (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:57:36)
    at buildRootChain.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:79:62)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:122:25)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at evaluateSync (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\gensync\index.js:251:28)
    at Function.sync (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\gensync\index.js:89:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\index.js:42:19)
    at transform (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\babelify\index.js:157:17)
    at BabelifyStream._flush (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\babelify\index.js:138:5)
    at BabelifyStream.prefinish (internal/streams/transform.js:147:10)
    at BabelifyStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at BabelifyStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at prefinish (internal/streams/writable.js:630:14)
    at finishMaybe (internal/streams/writable.js:638:5)
    at BabelifyStream.Writable.end (internal/streams/writable.js:582:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:577:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at DestroyableTransform.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at endReadableNT (C:\Egencia\GitCode\checkout-acceptance\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:1010:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

NodeV19.4.0

In my project there is no config file related to babel.config.<cjs/js/json> and added the below code in file

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: {
                    node: 'current'
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    plugins: ["transform-class-properties",{loosen : true}]
};
```

Still got the same error. Also try to downgrade Node Version from 19.4 to 14.15 but still facing same error.